# How to use klist to show kerberos principal instance URL?

Tags: linux, kerberos

When I type klist, it only shows the primary username and realm:

```
> klist -a
Ticket cache: FILE:...
Default principal: primary@REALM.NAME.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04/30/2017 21:03:00  05/01/2017 07:03:00  primary/REALM.NAME.COM@REALM.NAME.COM
    renew until 05/07/2017 21:02:56
    Addresses: (none)
```

The default principal doesn't have instance name included.

How to show it in klist? Or is it missing in my system?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

An instance principal is just another principal. I the credential cache was using one, it would be obvious. As it's not, it is reasonable to assume that the system was no configured to use on is this particular case. Also note that is it unusual for user principals to have instances, while it is common for server principals.

Below are credential caches for a user and for an `sssd` process.

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1234_WAE7Uw
Default principal: self@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/02/2017 09:35:03  05/02/2017 21:35:03  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 05/03/2017 09:35:03
05/02/2017 09:54:53  05/02/2017 21:35:03  ldap/ldap2.example.com@
    renew until 05/03/2017 09:35:03
05/02/2017 09:54:53  05/02/2017 21:35:03  ldap/ldap2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 05/03/2017 09:35:03
05/02/2017 09:55:04  05/02/2017 21:35:03  ldap/ldap1.example.com@
    renew until 05/03/2017 09:35:03
05/02/2017 09:55:04  05/02/2017 21:35:03  ldap/ldap1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 05/03/2017 09:35:03

$ sudo klist -c /tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM
icket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM
Default principal: host/desktop1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/02/2017 01:37:44  05/02/2017 13:37:44  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
05/02/2017 01:37:44  05/02/2017 13:37:44  nfs/nfs1.example.com@
05/02/2017 01:37:44  05/02/2017 13:37:44  nfs/nfs1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```